# Query starting from a previous query result - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I am facing a problem using MySQL schema and tables. More precisely, I would like to run a query where it starts by looking for certain tables in a preselected schema and then, it join all the fetched tables into just one big table (using `UNION`)

Here is what I have done so far:

```
SET @union_jan_tables = NULL;
SELECT
GROUP_CONCAT(
DISTINCT
CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ', table_name)
SEPARATOR '\r\nUNION\r\n'
)
INTO
@union_jan_tables
FROM
information_schema.tables
WHERE
table_schema = 'my_schema' AND table_name LIKE '%jan%';

SELECT @union_jan_tables;
```

It returns this:

```
'SELECT * FROM jan_2018

 UNION

 SELECT * FROM jan_2019'
```

Sadly, it return a row value which exactly is the query I would like to run. Hence, how can I say to MySQL Workbench to run that 'row'?

In addition, you could try to provide another different solution! It is highly accepted.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This appears to be an [XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) problem. I'm guessing that you have tables named by month/year name where you store certain data and you want to display data that belongs to particular month. Sadly, your design prevents you from issuing the query you're after. Instead of splitting stuff in tables which you name as `month_year`, you use a single table where you have a column named `month` and a column named `year` which lets you perform queries such as `SELECT x WHERE month = 'jan' AND year = '2018';`. Consider redesigning this.

Comment: If you want to execute dynamic SQL, you have to use `PREPARE` and `EXECUTE` in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to execute a dynamic sql, which you can do like this:

```
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @union_jan_tables;

EXECUTE stmt1;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```